# Responsive design fails to work in some (mobile) browsers

Tags: mobile, browser, media, viewport

I've been experimenting with my first responsive design, but i've hit a small brick wall.

When ajusting the size of my screen on my regular browser, it seems to break fine (one small, one large to start with):

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1px) {
@media screen and (max-width: 1300px) {
```

However, when I view it on a mobile phone, it seems to fail what i'm trying to achieve.

It seems to work on my HTC One in Chrome, but doesn't work on the default Android Browser.
It also fails on iPhone 4S, on both Safari and Chrome for iPhone.

I am using

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Any ideas as to where i'm going wrong?

Demo site: http://leafz.nl/new/

Edit: Screenshot of the layout on mobile browser (incorrect view): http://i41.tinypic.com/98t0ye.png

Regards,
Dave

Comment: "it seems to fail what i'm trying to achieve" - what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: To get the layout as it is on my normal browser, when I narrow down the width of the page.

As of now, it gives me a messed up layout on some mobile browsers, also not showing the background image...

Comment: Added screenshot of the messed up layout on mobile browser:
http://i41.tinypic.com/98t0ye.png

Comment: Sorry, but help me understand: Why should `@media screen and (min-width: 1px)` apply only to mobile browsers? And media querys that resides BEFORE non-media-queries in the CSS (see your #wrapper and .container code for instance) will not have any effect as they will be overwritten anyway... Always put the media queries in the end is a good rule.

Comment: The "@media screen and (min-width: 1px)" shouldn't necessarily [i]only[/i] work for mobile browsers, it was simply to test the smallest screens out there.

My media queries are at the end of my CSS file, is that incorrect use? I do understand some of the media query's may overwrite my 'default' CSS code prior to that, but that's not my concern as of yet. You can imagine the 'max 1300' will be a media query for '1100 <> 1300' margin or w/e further down the road. 

Currently, i'm simply trying to have 2 versions that work, which currently breaks at 1300px.

Comment: When I view your `style.css` file there are indeed non-media-queries after the media-queries.

Comment: And now you're not closing your @media brackets...